# Is this java Object eligible for garbage collection in List

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, garbage-collection

What I am asking might be a stupid question so please pardon me for that.
So it goes like this :

```
List<Boss> bossList = new ArrayList<Boss>();
Boss b = null;
for(Employee e : List<Employee> myList){
    b = new Boss();
    b.setEmployee(e);
    bossList.add(b);
    b = null;
}
```

So in above scenario, I am creating lot of Boss objects and then de-referencing them(I know I don't need to write "b = null", but i did it for clarity of my question). In normal scenario, I would have marked them to garbage collection, by doeing this, but because in this scenario, I am adding those Boss objects in List collection, are they marked for GC or not? If not then why? And how does List collection work internally to hold references for each Object added, so as to avoid garbage collection?

```
[EDIT]
```

The scope of question is only limited to the individual Boss objects created in `for` loop, considering that this method returns the reference of the  List to the outside world.

Comment: The object itself, which you put in the list, is obviously not available for GC since a reference to it still exists, even if you nullify `b`.

Comment: An object cannot be garbage collected if there is any way in the current program state for it to be reached (excluding through the special class WeakReference and its related classes). One reference, no matter where, from live code is enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ArrayList has `Object[] elementData` internally. When you added `b` to `bossList` ArrayList assigned `elementData[0] = b`. So when you assigned `null` to `b` the instance of `Boss` is still referenced from `elementData[0]` and cannot be GCed. But since `ArrayList` instance is referenced only from method's variable after the method returns both `ArrayList` and `Boss` instances will be eligible for GC.

Answer (score 10):

The `Boss` objects will not be collected by the `GarbageCollector` because they are still referenced in the code block that you are posted. `bossList` is an `ArrayList` which has an internal array of `Object` thus holding references to those objects which are added to it.

I such a situation not only the references by you are considered but all referneces in all objects involved.

**EDIT:** Since you are returning the List in your code the objects will not be marked for garbage collection until the list is no longer referenced in your program.

Comment: But since the `List<Boss>` is declared inside the method, then when the method finishes, the list would be marked for GC, thus the `Boss` object references will be marked as well.

Comment: Correct. As soon as the block in which the `ArrayList` is declared terminates all objects will be collected (if not further referenced).

Comment: Sure, if you're assuming that the list only exists within the method.

Comment: @system32 if these objects aren't referenced in other part of your program, then yes, they will be marked for GC.

Comment: if List<Boss> object is returned by the method to the outside world then ofcourse it will not be GCed. Ofcourse the point of question is not aimed at the List<Boss> object, but rather at the Boss objects created in FOR loop.

Comment: @DanielLerps then you should specify that in your answer since OP hasn't defined this in the question.

Comment: Edited the answer according to suggestions of BheshGurung and LuiggiMendoza and the updated question.

Comment: @DanielLerps Generally speaking, no one object will be eligible for GC till there is any link to it (directly or through other objects) in any existent stack.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what really happens with your code :

[image: Hello]

Answer (score -1):

Since java is pass by reference, whenever you add `b` to `bossList`, `bossList` starts referencing the memory location which b is pointing to. So when `b` nullified only link from `b` to the reference is broken. Thus keeping the object accessible through `bossList`.