# Adding object to ArrayList without reference

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, reference

Can I add an object to an `ArrayList` without a reference?

For example, can I add object as below:

```
ArrayList<Dog> list=new ArrayList<Dog>();      
list.add(new Dog);
```

Comment: Why don't you give it a try!!!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this:

```
list.add(new Dog);
```

but this:

```
list.add(new Dog());
```

**Why can this be done?**

Actually is quite simple, **`JVM` will automatically keep a reference of the created object** inside the `List` to keep it alive, so you don't have to care about. As usual, if this object is removed from the list and not referenced anywhere else, will be elegible for `Garbage Collector`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Once you add the object to arrayList, what matters in only where the object is in the heap. It does not matter, you add it with reference or without.

But yes, it should be `list.add(new Dog())`.

You are missing the paranthesis after `Dog`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

If you don't reference the new dog anywhere else, it will be up for garbage collection as soon as the list is eligible for garbage collection. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16850558/12039).

In addition to the other suggested improvements to your example code, you should

- Use the [diamond operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#diamond)
- Prefer `List` over `ArrayList` (see [Why should the interface for a Java class be preferred?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147468/why-should-the-interface-for-a-java-class-be-prefered))

Your code would then look like this:

```
List<Dog> list = new ArrayList<>();   
list.add(new Dog());
```